# CentOS Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill int during bootup

Tags: linux, boot, centos, kernel, kernel-panic

Building has a annual power shutdown for maintenance for 2 days.

As such, prior to it, I have shut down the CentOS 6 server.

After the power is back on (2 days later), when I boot back up, I encountered the following image :

[image: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill int]

I've Googled search around, and the most common answer is to disable SELinux during the boot.
I have tried that - and it didnt helped (which made sense since I didn't touched SELinux).

Also, at the GRUB page, I tried booting into other kernel, 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 kernel - however, it encountered the same kernel panic.

I'm unsure if its due to hardware issues like disk failing, RAMs etc, or other issues

Update 1 :

- I removed rghb and quiet parameters when booting the kernel, and there are more logs, specifically saying that lv_root and lv_swap could not be found.
- Tried using rescue USB thumbdrive. However after selecting “Rescued installed system”, it has problem locating the system partition. Even explicitly stating the disk that contains the system, it has error.
- Tried using live DVD as thumbdrive instead. In the live environment, mounting /dev/sda gives me error stating wrong file system : isw_raid_member. I believe it’s because my OS disk is configured as raid1(mirror) using mdadm. Googling around and I discovered “dmraid -ay”, which seems to sync /dev/sda and /dev/sdb as a volume. However, when I tried to mount the volume, it keeps saying that it is already mounted or the mount folder is busy.

At this point, I’m not sure what to do. My main priority is to retrieve the files instead

Comment: During the power maintenance, was your computer connected to the mains? Any other devices act funny?

Comment: @harrymc, the server is connected to the mains - however, all main switches were turned off

Comment: I think you should split the “rescue files” part from the “make it boot again” part of the question. // Judging from the error messages, you have LVM on top of a firmware FakeRAID. After `dmraid -ay`, try `vgs` to see whether the volume group is detected.

Comment: FYI:  Your kernel version is crazy old 2.6, version 6.6.4 is current.  Whatever is causing the panic has probably been long since fixed in a newer kernel version.  use "df -h" to show a list of mounted devices, maybe it is already mounted and you just need to point at the correct reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dmraid -ay`, and a combination of commands like `pvscan`, `vgscan`, `lvscan` (which scans all the existing volumes/partitions) and subsequently doing `vgchange -ay` and `lvchange -ay`, I was able to mount my root and home partitions and backup the data.

After backing up the data, I continued to fiddle with the system. I tried changing my SATA configuration from AHCI to RAID. But, that doesn't solve the issue. However, when I go to last section of the BIOS, where there's a `Boot override` section, I saw there's a `Intel Volume0`. Selecting `Intel Volume0`, I was able to boot back the system into CentO - strange.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).